# Removing unknown number of markers each time the function is called [Google Maps API android]

Tags: java, android, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-markers

I'm using **googles map api** for android devices and  I have a **function which generate markers all over the map**, the function is called every couple of seconds and the markers place may change, therefor **I need a way to remove all the irrelevant markers and i don't know how to remove a bunch of them** while i don't know how many of them i have.

my function looks like this:

```
                        JSONObject counter = jObj.getJSONObject(String.valueOf(x));
                    while (counter.getString("untilwhen")!= "true")
                    {
                        JSONObject lat = jObj.getJSONObject(String.valueOf(x));
                        String latitude = lat.getString("latitude");
                        JSONObject lon = jObj.getJSONObject(String.valueOf(x));
                        String longitude = lon.getString("longitude");
                        LatLng latLng1 = new LatLng(Double.parseDouble(latitude), Double.parseDouble(longitude));
                        mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(latLng1).title("user"));
                        x = x+1;
                        counter = jObj.getJSONObject(String.valueOf(x));
                    }
```

how can i make `mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(latLng1).title("user"));` remove all the old one and replace them with the new.

hope you understood...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to keep track of your markers you have on the map. `addMarker` returns a marker so put that in a list or else call `clear()` to remove all the markers on your map